# Automatically open most recent CSV file in the folder

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to program a sequence in VBA where the program will pull the most recent CSV file from a specific folder and input the query table in cell A1 on the sheet. Right now it is only letting me pull .TXT files which I cannot seem to format into the correct table. Any ideas?

Thanks!
    Sub GetMostRecentFile()

```
Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFile As String
Dim dteFile As Date
Dim Ws As Worksheet

'set path for files - change for your folder
Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Refresh Test"

'set up filesys objects
Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)


'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then 
store Filename
dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
        dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
        strFile = objFile.Name
    End If
Next objFile

Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="Text;" & strFile, 
Destination:=Ws.Range("A1"))
 .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Set FileSys = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `GetExtensionName` method of the file system object to test that mask is csv i.e. `FileSys.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "csv"`

For my locale (I don't know if this varies) I also had to switch these.

```
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
```

to this

```
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
```

So maybe review those settings for what you actually need.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetMostRecentFile()

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim myFolder
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim dteFile As Date
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    'set path for files - change for your folder
    Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Refresh Test"

    'set up filesys objects
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)

    Dim Filename As String
    'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then
    'store Filename
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files

        If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile And FileSys.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "csv" Then
            dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strFile = objFile.Name
        End If
    Next objFile

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="Text;" & strFile, Destination:=Ws.Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter =True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        Set FileSys = Nothing
        Set myFolder = Nothing

    End With
End Sub
```

**Or**

Version 2 With command line. Credit to @FlorentB for solving the last part of the command string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997069/how-to-return-value-of-command-line-variable-to-immediate-window)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMostRecentFile()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, fileName As String
    Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Refresh Test"

    fileName = Replace$(Trim$(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /V /C cd " & myDir & " && (for /f ""eol=: delims="" %F in ('dir /b /od *.csv') do @set ""newest=%F"" ) && echo !newest!").StdOut.ReadAll), vbNewLine, "")

    If fileName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="Text;" & (myDir & Application.PathSeparator & fileName), Destination:=Ws.Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It also turned out my folder destinations were formatted without a \ at the end which caused errors during the file look up.