# Get an echo batch-file answer with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

In my VBA code I call the bat using `Call Shell(....)`.

I need now to get the "Echo answer" inside the batch-file in VBA.

How can I do that?

My batch-file:

```
@echo off
IF exist %3 (robocopy %1 %2 /e ) ELSE (echo 1)
```

I want to get that "1" in VBA.

Comment: Please include your code and expected return value.

Comment: There you have.

Comment: Did you have a look at these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba

Comment: @QHarr Oo That one's top upvoted answer uses a 14-line function for something I usually just do in a one-liner. And accepted answer uses a whole bunch of WinAPI stuff for it!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I know. I used the same as you in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073239/6241235

Comment: Yes @QHarr. I take a look to that answer before, but mi lvl of knowledge makes me feel indifferent with that kind of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return answers using `Call Shell`. You need to use `WScript.Shell`, and can use the read lines from the execution object it returns.

```
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim ex As Object
Set ex = sh.Exec("C:\Path\To\File.bat")
Dim ans As String
ans = ex.StdOut.ReadAll
```

A shorthand, if you want to save lines:

```
Dim ans As String
ans = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:\Path\To\File.bat").StdOut.ReadAll
```